# Passing datum to D3 function - Ext JS 4.2.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, d3.js

I am trying to implement something like this using D3, within an Ext JS 4.2 application.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

In D3, 'path.attr("d", linkArc);', calls the linkArc function and passes datum to linkArc function. This works fine in the D3 world.

```js
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);
  circle.attr("transform", transform);
  text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}
```

However, I am trying to use this within Ext JS (D3 JS is loaded in the afterRender() function) -

```js
(function() {
 
Ext.define("d3.widgets.D3Widgets", {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    alias: 'widget.d3_workflow',
    width: 800,
    height: 400, 
 circle : '',
 text : '',
    constructor: function(config) {
      ...
    },

    
    initComponent : function() {
     ...
    },

    afterRender: function() {
        this.loadScript(this.onD3Loaded, this);
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    },

 loadScript: function(callback, scope) {
  Ext.Loader.injectScriptElement('http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js', this.onLoad, this.onError, this);
  
    },

    onError : function() {
  console.log('On Error');
 },
 
 onLoad : function() {

  var nodes = {};
  
  var links = [
    {source: "Initiate", target: "Department Approver Approves", type: "licensing"},
    {source: "Department Approver Approves", target: "Division Approver Approves", type: "licensing"},
    {source: "Division Approver Approves", target: "End", type: "suit"}
  ];

  links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
  });

  var width = 960,
   height = 500;
   
  var path = ''; 

  var force = d3.layout.force()
   .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
   .links(links)
   .size([width, height])
   .linkDistance(60)
   .charge(-300)
   .on("tick", this.tick(path))
   .start();

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);

  // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
  svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
   .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
    .enter().append("marker")
   .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
   .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
   .attr("refX", 15)
   .attr("refY", -1.5)
   .attr("markerWidth", 6)
   .attr("markerHeight", 6)
   .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
   .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

  var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
   .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("path")
   .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
   .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

  circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
   .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("circle")
   .attr("r", 6)
   .call(force.drag);

  text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
   .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text")
   .attr("x", 8)
   .attr("y", ".31em")
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  
 },
 
 
    onRender :function(ct, position) {     
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

     // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
 tick: function(path)  {
   console.log('Inside Tick --');
   path.attr("d", linkArc);
   circle.attr("transform", transform);
   text.attr("transform", transform);
 },

 linkArc: function(d) {
   var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
    dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
   return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
 },

 transform: function(d) {
   return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
 }

});

})();
```

In the tick function, linkArc function is called using

path.attr("d", linkArc);

and linkArc function is defined as

linkArc: function(d) {
}

In Ext JS, when this is run, I get the following error in browser console -

Uncaught ReferenceError: linkArc is not defined

It seems this is happening because linkArc is expecting datum, which is not getting passed.

Should this function be called differently in Ext JS?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused since `linkArc` is not defined in the scope of `tick` function. Either you have to define that function inside `tick` function or use it as shown the code below.

**Solution 1:**

```
tick: function(path)  {
      var widget = this;
      console.log('Inside Tick --');
      path.attr("d", widget.linkArc);
      circle.attr("transform", widget.transform);
      text.attr("transform", widget.transform);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
tick: function(path)  {
      function linkArc(d) {
           var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
           dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
           dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
           return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
      };
      function transform(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      } 
      console.log('Inside Tick --');
      path.attr("d", linkArc);
      circle.attr("transform", transform);
      text.attr("transform", transform);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Gilsha said, this is a problem with the scope. But you also have to add the correct pointer to `transform`, as it won't give you an error but it won't work properly.

Here is the code I used and fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lr6

```
Ext.application({
        name: 'Fiddle',

        launch: function() {
            Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                width: 900,
                height: 500,
                itemId : 'd3TestWindow',
                title: 'Custom D3',
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: function(window) {
                        var nodes = {};
                        links.forEach(function(link) {
                            link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
                                name: link.source
                            });
                            link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
                                name: link.target
                            });
                        });

                        window.force = d3.layout.force().nodes(d3.values(nodes)).links(links).size([window.getWidth(), window.getHeight()]).linkDistance(60).charge(-300).on("tick", window.tick).start();

                        window.svg = d3.select("#" + window.id + "-innerCt").append("svg").attr("width", window.getWidth()).attr("height", window.getHeight());
                        window.appendPath();
                        window.appendCircle();
                        window.appendText();

                        // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
                        window.svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker").data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"]).enter().append("marker").attr("id", function(d) {
                            return d;
                        }).attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10").attr("refX", 15).attr("refY", - 1.5).attr("markerWidth", 6).attr("markerHeight", 6).attr("orient", "auto").append("path").attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");



                    }
                },
                appendPath : function () {
                    var me = this;
                    this.path = this.svg.append("g").selectAll("path").data(me.force.links()).enter().append("path").attr("class", function(d) {
                        return "link " + d.type;
                    }).attr("marker-end", function(d) {
                        return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
                    });
                },
                appendCircle: function() {
                    var me = this;
                    this.circle = this.svg.append("g").selectAll("circle").data(me.force.nodes()).enter().append("circle").attr("r", 6).call(me.force.drag);
                },
                appendText: function() {
                    var me = this;
                    this.text = this.svg.append("g").selectAll("text").data(me.force.nodes()).enter().append("text").attr("x", 8).attr("y", ".31em").text(function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    });
                },
                transform: function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                },
                linkArc: function(d) {
                    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
                },
                tick :  function() {
                    var window = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#d3TestWindow')[0];
                    window.path.attr("d", window.linkArc);
                    window.circle.attr("transform", window.transform);
                    window.text.attr("transform", window.transform);
                }
            }).show();
        }
    });
```